# how to display same page in nested lists when refresh the page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

I developing a mobile application using spring 3 mvc, jquery mobile 1.2 and HDIV.

I have a nested list in my application. My problem is When I refresh the browser in the nested lists, the browser takes me on main page. How to stop the refresh in jquery mobile and how to display same list page in nested lists ?

I want exactly like the following...  http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0a3/#docs/lists/lists-nested.html&ui-page=Planes-1

any help ?

thanks & regards

Answer (score 0):

1. You can change your url to have the path to your page that you want to display:
   http://www.yourhost.com/inde.htm#mypagename
2. or $.mobile.changePage(...
3. or $.mobile.loadPage(...
   for more info just look on: http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/api/methods.html